# Joomla css file rewrites it self

Tags: css, joomla

I was wondering why .css file rewrite itself on Joomla.

I have bought Joomla template. In template manger under general settings I am using Development Mode On. If I use Development Mode OFF I am not able to change .css files.

For example: I am using theme which is located in t3-assets/dev/ theme i choose

When I use On mode I find section I want to change, it works. But after some time it rewrites it self. I was wondering how to prevent that if possible?

Comment: If you purchased it, the best place to ask for support is to the company who sold you the template.

Comment: If it is a modern component you should never do css directly, only edit LESS or add new LESS files.

Answer (score 0):

Some templates are overwritten alone , go to your server and take off the writing mode in the template folder.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the template is using LESS, so CSS are compiled each time you modify LESS. If that is the case, you should not prevent it, but find the correct way to include your modifications (probably there's a "custom.less" or similar file for that).